# How can I use Xamarin's Storyboard and F#

Tags: ios, f#, xamarin

since its not (yet) possible to use the Storyboard for generating classes and glue code. I had the idea to write the F# classes on my own and do the glueing myself.

So I written this loading of the Storyboard namespace

```
open System
open MonoTouch.UIKit
open MonoTouch.Foundation

[<Register("AppDelegate")>]
type AppDelegate() = 
    inherit UIApplicationDelegate()

    member val window = null with get, set

    override this.FinishedLaunching(app, options) = 
        this.window <- new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds)
        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard", null)
        this.window.RootViewController <- Storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController() :?> UIViewController
        this.window.MakeKeyAndVisible()
        true

module Main = 
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args = 
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate")
        0
```

and the following controller class

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open MonoTouch.UIKit
open MonoTouch.Foundation

[<Register("HomeController")>]
type HomeController() = 
    inherit UIViewController()

    override this.ViewDidLoad() = 
        base.ViewDidLoad()
        System.Console.WriteLine("FOO!")
```

Then I created the Storyboard (see attached pictures).
[image: Views]
[image: properties]

AND - everything gets loaded and the storyboard works fine - One exception:  ViewDidLoadnever gets called. Obviously I was not successful in attaching my hand coded controller.

Does anybody have an idea how do accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of creating a Controller without parameters

```
[<Register("HomeController")>]
type HomeController() = 
    inherit UIViewController()
```

One must create a controller with an pointer and init the base controller with that pointer too.

```
[<Register("HomeController")>]
type HomeController(handle:IntPtr) = 
    inherit UIViewController(handle)
```

### To attach the controls on the view with the view controller (e.g. attach the button named "Clicker")

[image][image]

one has to add the following code to your view controller

```
[<Register("HomeController")>]
type HomeController(handle:IntPtr) = 
    inherit UIViewController(handle)

    let mutable _Clicker = new UIButton()

    [<Outlet>]
    member this.Clicker 
           with get() = _Clicker
           and set value = _Clicker <- value
```

Comment: The property can be expressed more simply (maybe due to new features since this answer?): `[<Outlet>] member val Clicker = new UIButton() with get, set`

Comment: It might also be a better idea to use `null :> UIButton` instead of `new UIButton()` since the actual instance will be provided by the storyboard runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an iOS type provider that's still considered experimental. You can try the template here https://github.com/nosami/ios-type-provider-template but this only works with the built in storyboard designer.

The `myButton` identifier [here](https://github.com/nosami/ios-type-provider-template/blob/214f84f2f4a738a34a6860e63dd3a1b856b15f9b/iostp2/ViewController.fs#L23) is provided by the type provider based on the controls in the storyboard.